# Angularjs ng-repeat filter works in v1.0.1 not v1.3.7

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In this example http://plnkr.co/edit/blAbw9eKiUpJWxSvHtmj?p=preview

```
<html ng-app="Testing">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.7" data-semver="1.3.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
   <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.js"></script> -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="TestContr">

Search in contacts:     <input ng-model="filterQuery" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <ul ng-repeat="md in mydata | filter:filterQuery">
      <li>{{md.company}} ({{md.city}} || {{md.customer_id}})
            <ul ng-repeat="sub in md.contacts | filter:filterQuery">
          <li>{{sub.name}} ({{sub.phone}})</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>

var app = angular.module('Testing', []);

app.controller('TestContr', function($scope) {
  $scope.mydata = [
  {
        "company":"Test Company",
        "city":"New York",
        "customer_id":"123",
        "contacts":[
            {
                "phone":"0129385439",
                "name":"Frank"
            },
            {
                "phone":"0129385444",
                "name":"Mary"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "company":"Example Ltd.",
        "city":"Tokyo",
        "customer_id":"353",
        "contacts":[
            {
                "phone":"0081123456879",
                "name":"Matsumoto"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "company":"B.I.G. Inc.",
        "city":"Dehli",
        "customer_id":"763",
        "contacts":[
            {
                "phone":"00454621011",
                "name":"John"
            },
            {
                "phone":"00454621077",
                "name":"Franky"
            },
            {
                "phone":"00454621015",
                "name":"Marc"
            },
            {
                "phone":"00454621001",
                "name":"Anna"
            }
        ]
    }
];
});
```

I am trying to filter a list of data and its sub-list data.  I've noticed that it works as expected, if I try to search for 'Anna', in Angular v1.0.1 but not in Angular v1.3.7. (uncomment the 1.0.1 version script tag in the example to see this working as expected)

My question is what needs to be changed on the page when using Angular v1.3.7 for this to filter properly as it does in Angular v1.0.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to use 1.3.8. It works as you expect.

See the following plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/l70aA2Q2OYrVwhZB41Qr?p=preview

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```